# RegEx - Split string by word

Tags: .net, regex, string

I've been trying to write a sort of surreal text adventure game for my daughter, everything has been going well but I've got stuck with trying to process a particular input with RegEx.

The input string needs to begin with a number (optionally decimal), followed by either a series of characters (min 1, max *n*) immediately followed by a whitespace, then *and*, **or** followed instead by a white-space and then *n* amount of words (no numbers) until the split word (and). Any words after "and" need to be captured as well in another group.

So an example valid input might be:

```
5 blue cows and a bucket of milk
```

or

```
2.5mph and a really slow car
```

and split into three groups like so:

```
[5] [blue cows] [a bucket of milk] or [2.5] [mph] [a really slow car]
```

Being new to RegEx I'm going to apologise in advance for my terrible attempts, but I believe I need to use a **lookahead**?

My attempts so far look a bit like this:

Works fine but only captures a single word each side, eg: *[5]*  *[blue]*  *[a]*

```
^(\d*\.?\d*)\s*([a-z]*)\s*\band\b\s([a-z]+)
```

And this one using the lookahead captures multiple words as expected but each individual character is captured separately:

```
^(\d*\.?\d*)\s*(.?)+(?=and)\s*\band\b\s((.?)+)
```

Any help would be really appreciated, especially as my daughter's answer to the problem was something along the lines of *"Daddy you should shave off your moustache, then it would work?"*

Cheers guys :)

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you didn't include the space in the matching group. Check this regex:

```
^(\d*\.?\d*)\s*([a-z\s]*)\sand\s([a-z\s]*)$
```